# SQL identifying one hit wonders Youtube channel

Tags: postgresql

I was given this question awhile back and I'm trying to solve it. Given a hypothetical table, how would you identify one hit wonder Youtube channel where 75% of views are coming from a single video? Below is the code that I have but I'm not sure if it's correct. Please keep in mind you can add/remove anything in the hypothetical table such as adding a new column if you like.

youtube_table

| channel_name | views | video_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr Beast | 125943320 | Selling Houses For $1 |
| 3blue1brown | 7753923 | But how does bitcoin actually work? |

```
with t1 as 
(select channel_name, video_name, max(views) as max_views
from youtube_table
group by 1, 2),

t2 as 
(select channel_name, sum(views) as sum_views
from youtube_table yt
group by 1),

t3 as 
(select t1.channel_name, t1.video_name, cast(t1.max_views as numeric)*100/t2.sum_views as percent_view
from t1
join t2
on t1.channel_name = t2.channel_name )

select * from t3
where t3.percent_view > 70
```

Comment: Forget SQL for a minute. Just think about the algorithm. What would you do? How about the # of views for each video divided by the sum total of the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you need slightly more realistic sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE youtube_table(
   channel_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,views        BIGINT  NOT NULL
  ,video_name   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO youtube_table(channel_name,views,video_name) VALUES ('Mr Beast',125943320,'Selling Houses For $1');
INSERT INTO youtube_table(channel_name,views,video_name) VALUES ('Mr Beast',1259,'Selling Houses For $10');
INSERT INTO youtube_table(channel_name,views,video_name) VALUES ('3blue1brown',17753923,'But how does bitcoin actually work?');
INSERT INTO youtube_table(channel_name,views,video_name) VALUES ('3blue1brown',8753923,'But how does forex actually work?');
INSERT INTO youtube_table(channel_name,views,video_name) VALUES ('3blue1brown',4753923,'But how do shares actually work?');
```

then the following will locate the videos with an overall channel percentage larger than 75

```
select
*
from (
select
  channel_name
, video_name
, views as video_views
, sum(views) over(partition by channel_name) as channel_views
, (views * 100.0) / sum(views) over(partition by channel_name) channel_view_pct
from youtube_table
) as yt
where channel_view_pct > 75.0
```

the result would be:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
| channel_name |      video_name       | video_views | channel_views |  channel_view_pct   |
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
| Mr Beast     | Selling Houses For $1 |   125943320 |     125944579 | 99.9990003539572751 |
+--------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

To add the restriction for "one hit wonder" then:

```
select
*
from (
    select
    *
    , count(case when video_views >= channel_views * .75 then 1 end) over(partition by channel_name, video_name) as channel_count
    from (
            select
              channel_name
            , video_name
            , views as video_views
            , sum(views) over(partition by channel_name) as channel_views
            from youtube_table
        ) as yt
    ) as y
where channel_count = 1
```

*available as a demonstration @db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5bd4af286a9f955d0df99f84212e9cdf)*

Answer (score 1):

> identify one hit wonder Youtube channel where 75% of views are coming from a single video

```sql
SELECT channel_name
FROM   youtube_table
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING max(views) >= sum(views) * .75;
```